# Dropdown com clique

Tags: html, css

Criei um HTML e CSS de um menu porém não consigo criar o Dropdown com clique, apenas quando passa o mouse o menu recolhe ou expande e eu gostaria de fazer com um clique. Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

```css
*{ margin: 0; paddin: 0;}
body {background: ffffff; margin: 5px; }
#nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#nav li {list-style: none; background: #fff; width: 250 px; border-bottom: 1px solid #666;}
#nav li a {display: block; padding: 8px; border-left: 4px solid #444; text-decoration: none; box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #ccc; color: #555;}
#nav li a:hover {border-left:4px solid #069; background: #f8f8f8;}
#nav li ul{display: none;}
#nav li:hover ul { display: block; cursor:pointer;}
#nav li:hover ul li{background: #333;}
#nav li:hover ul li a {color:ccc;}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{background: #222; border-left:4px solid #900;}
```

```html
<ul id="nav"> 
  <li><a href="#">Consultores</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">sub - 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub - 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub - 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
  <li><a href="#">Colaboradores</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Comercial</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">RH</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Está bem difícil de entender. Você consegue editar a pergunta e colocar o seu CSS como código? Adiciona o HTML também.

Comment: Você já tentou ao invés de :hover usar um :focus?
Acho que funciona ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Só com CSS você poderia usar um `label` com `checkbox` (oculto) apenas no botão que abre o submenu, em vez de usar um link `<a>`. Ao usar um link `<a>` com `href="#"` apenas para abrir o submenu, irá alterar a URL adicionando o `#`.

Ao clicar no `label` irá marcar/desmarcar o checkbox, e você pode usar a pseudo-classe `:checked` no checkbox para mostrar/ocultar o submenu. Coloque o input após o label e adicione um `id` no checkbox e um `for` na label apontando para a `id`:

```css
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {background: ffffff; margin: 5px; }
#nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#nav li {list-style: none; background: #fff; width: 250 px; border-bottom: 1px solid #666; outline: none;}
#nav li a, #nav li label {display: block; padding: 8px; border-left: 4px solid #444; text-decoration: none; box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #ccc; color: #555; cursor: pointer;}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li label:hover {border-left:4px solid #069; background: #f8f8f8;}
#nav li ul, #nav li input{display: none;}
#nav li:hover ul li{background: #333;}
#nav li:hover ul li a {color:ccc;}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{background: #222; border-left:4px solid #900;}
#nav li input:checked + ul{
   display: block; cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav"> 
   <li>
      <label for="sub1">Consultores</label>
      <input id="sub1" type="checkbox">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">sub - 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">sub - 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">sub - 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li> 
  <li><a href="#">Colaboradores</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Comercial</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">RH</a></li>

</ul>
```

> Tem um erro de digitação na primeira linha do seu CSS: `paddin` seria
>   `padding`.

Comment: Mas essa aplicação é semanticamente incorreta. Além de ir contra as  [regras semânticas do W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CheckBox) os leitores de tela lerão esse elemento como uma opção de formulário. A solução aqui deveria ser uma função de JS.

Comment: Boa observação. Mas os leitores de tela não ignoram elementos com display: none?

Comment: Ignora sim, você tem razão. Mas o label vai ficar aparecendo. E ainda é uma má prática semanticamente. Tem muita gente discutindo o uso semântico disso, mas maioria concorda que é 'gambi'. Dá uma olhada [nesse post](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) e nos comentários.

Comment: Pq má prática semanticamente? Essa parte eu não entendi.

Comment: Imagina que o HTML é a língua portuguesa, você pode falar "Mim não querer", dá pra entender mas tá errado. Aqui é a mesma coisa, todo elemento HTML tem um propósito e deve ser usado para isso. Usar uma palavra ou um tag HTML fora de cotexto é semanticamente errado para seu respectivo idioma. O `label` [define o rótulo de um item de formulário](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp), e só deve ser usado para isso.

Comment: Então não deveriam usar href=#, seguindo essa mesma lógica. Porque um link deve ser um link, e não um botão.

Comment: Exato! Vou mudar o código. Que bom que você notou.

Comment: Nem tinha visto a sua resposta rs... Depois vou analisar

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde, pelo que entendi você não está usando nenhum framework, neste caso de uma olhada nesse [código](https://jsfiddle.net/NFTFw/29/), ele mostra como fazer, basta adaptar no seu código.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $div = $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown);
      $div.toggle();
      $("div.dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
      return false;
    });

});
    
  $('html').click(function(){
    $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
  });
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para funcionar será necessário importar jquery na sua aplicação.

só não edito seu código inteiro pq estou sem tempo, mas isso resolve.

Comment: Olá Renan, poderia postar uma parte do código aqui ou explicar melhor a resposta? É possível por um código executável na resposta no botão Trecho HTML/CSS/JavaScript ou com o atalho do teclado `Ctrl + M`.

Comment: Editei, vê se assim fico melhor.

Comment: O ideal seria manter a hierarquia de listas (`ul` `li`) como estava na pergunta, pois é a forma mais 'correta' em termos de semãntica, boas práticas e acessibilidade. Além disso não é aconselhável inserir `style` no código e adicionar um listener em todo HTML para sempre ser ativo no clique independente do estado do dropdown, é um processamento desnecessário. Talvez precisasse ter uma função checando se o dropdown está aberto mas até isso iria rodar ao todo clique na tela.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples e correta de ter o resultado esperado seria adicionar um javascript (ou jQuery) que ative o `li` quando seu link é clicado com uma classe de CSS, e então você controla o efeito visual via CSS (em alguns casos também é feita a animação via JS, mas animações via CSS são aceleradas por hardware e têm um desempenho visual e de processamento muito melhor). É assim que maioria dos frameworks trabalham.

Segue mais ou menos o código (com JS bem fraco).

```js
$(".nav li > span").click(function() {
 // confesso que esse código parece pouco otimizado, aceito sugestões
 $parent_list_item = $(this).parent("li");
 // Remove todas as classes ativas de todos os itens dessa lista, para não ter 2 ativos ao mesmo tempo no mesmo dropdown. Mas ignora o item atual para checarmos depois de precisamos minimizar-lo
$parent_list_item.parent("ul").find(".active").not($parent_list_item).removeClass("active");
 // adiciona classe ativa para o <li> (pai) do <a> clicado, se ele não for o item que já está ativo
 if (!$parent_list_item.hasClass("active")) {
  $parent_list_item.addClass("active");
 }else{
  // Se for o que já está ativo remove a classe
  $parent_list_item.removeClass("active");
 }
});
```

```css
body{
 padding:20px;
}
/* apenas para visualização */
.nav{
 width:400px;
}
/* reseta as listas em .nav */
.nav, .nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
/* estiliza todos os botões dentro de nav */
.nav a,
.nav span{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition:all .3s ease; /* essa animação é entre a cor de fundo e cor da fonte, sempre muito útil */
}
/* posiciona o item relativo para os subitens (flutuantes) respeitarem sua posição */
.nav li{
 position:relative;
}
/* estiliza o primeiro nível */
.nav > li > a,
.nav > li > span{
 padding:10px;
 background:#eee;
 margin-bottom:1px;
 color:#333;
}
.nav li > span{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.nav li > span:after{
  display:inline-block;
  content:"+";
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:16px;
  float:right;
  line-height:1em;
}
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > span:hover{
 background:green;
 color:white;
}
/* estiliza todos os subitems, ou seja, a lista pode ter vários subdropdowns. Está flutuante pois inseri position:absolute, se você remover o item mostra abaixo;*/
.nav li > ul{
 position:absolute; /* comente esta linha para mostrar abaixo*/
 top:100%;
 z-index:2;
 background:#aaa;
 max-height:0; /* limita a altura para animarmos (obs este elemento não pode ter padding) */
 overflow:hidden;
 transition:all 0.5s ease; /* anima os estados do elemento */
 /*left: 100%; /* descomente esta linha para mostrar ao lado invés de abaixo */
 width:100%; /* deixa o submenu com a largura do pai, depende do caso, ele sobrepõe todos os filhos nesse caso, que não é bom */
 margin-left:5px; /* um espaçamento pra ficar visualmente compreensível os níveis */
}
/* 2º nível */
.nav li  ul > li > a,
.nav li  ul > li > span{
 padding:9px;
 font-size:0.9em;
 border-bottom:1px solid white;
 color:#666;
}
.nav li > ul > li > a:hover,
.nav li > ul > li > span:hover{
 background:tomato;
 color:white;
}
/* 3º nível */
.nav li > ul > li > ul > li > a,
.nav li > ul > li > ul > li > span{
 padding:7px;
 font-size:0.8em;
 border-bottom:1px solid white;
 color:#666;
}
.nav li > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover,
.nav li > ul > li > ul > li > span:hover{
 background:limegreen;
 color:white;
}
/* estiliza o link dentro do item quando está ativo */
.nav li.active > a,
.nav li.active > span{
 background:#333;
 color:#fff;
}
.nav li.active > span:after{
 content:"-";
}

.nav li.active > ul{
 max-height:100vh; /* remove a limitação de altura para animar para height:auto.*/
    animation:0s 1s delay-overflow forwards; /* pequeno hack para o overflow mudar apenas para o item aberto depois da animação terminada */
}

@keyframes delay-overflow {
  to { overflow:visible; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav"> 
  <li><span>Consultores</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#0">sub - 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">sub - 2</a></li>
      <li><span>sub - 3 (com subs)</span> <!-- como aqui é um botão simples de ordenação, ele não deve ser um link -->
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#0">sub sub - 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#0">sub sub - 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#0">sub sub - 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
  <li><a href="#0">Colaboradores</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Comercial</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">RH</a></li>
</ul>
```

Eu acho estranho como o stackoverflow insere o código direto na página, então sempre uso alternativas como o CodePen, [clique aqui para ver essa solução](https://codepen.io/teefars/pen/drZvqr).

Outras observações sobre seu código:

- Tente não usar `ID`s em elementos que podem ser genéricos / modularizados / componentizados ou repetíveis na página, tente tratar o ID apenas para seleções JS específicas. Ex: a página pode ter vários dropdowns, então o componente é genérico.

Espero ter ajudado (apesar desse JS ainda me incomodar rs)